# Symbian crashes with: FAULT: KERN 0x00000004 (4)

Tags: symbian

I have a Symbian application which is running fine for a while but after requesting
the same sequence of operations for the 10th time or so the Kernel suddenly crashes and
I get the following error message:

```
FAULT: KERN 0x00000004 (4)
```

Could anyone help me out what could cause such a Kernel fault?

Many thanks!

Comment: on the phone or in the emulator?

Comment: it fails when running on the hardware basically; So there is a different meaning with this error depending if it is running on the emulator or hardware?

Comment: you might actually have found a bug in your device firmware. Post more info: device model, firmware version, code...

Answer (score 2):

From [Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/infocenter/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/SystemPanics/KernPanics.html):

```
 This fault is raised when a system thread has panicked or terminated 
 causing the entire system to re-boot.
```

In Symbian a thread can be marked a system thread if it is responsible for some fundamental OS service which will always be running. Examples include the file server (file-system) and the windows server but there are others.

In your case it depends on what your application is trying to do. I'd dare guess there is an invalid use of the Symbian APIs or that you're not freeing some resource properly.